# Use loop to clear. textBox[i].Clear(). Is this possible?

Tags: c#, loops, variables

I am just looking to know this to try and clean up my code, and also for future reference.

I have a number of textBoxes.

```
        tbPart1.Clear();
        tbPart2.Clear();
        tbPart3.Clear();
        tbPart4.Clear();
        tbPart5.Clear();
        tbPart6.Clear();
        tbPart7.Clear();
```

Is there any way I could use a loop to replace the numbers?

I tried this, but have no idea how i could run the string.

```
        for (int i = 1; i == 7; i++)
        {
            string p = "tbPart" + i.ToString() + ".Clear";
        }
```

Comment: Are these the only text boxes in your application?  Is this Forms, WPF, ASP or something else?

Comment: Sorry, Windows Form, C#. My bad. I have about 20 or so to clear. These are just a few.

Comment: for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) !?!?

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Inside of the form's code (i.e. in a button click event handler), you can enumerate through all of the `TextBox` controls on the form and perform a specific action on them:

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(x => x.Clear());
```

If you need to only clear *some* of the `TextBox` controls, you can provide a sort of filter like so:

```
this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    // Add a condition to clear only some of the text boxes - i.e. those named "tbPart..."
    .Where(x=>x.Name.StartsWith("tbPart"))
    .ToList().ForEach(x => x.Clear());
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest.  I guess people named Michael think alike.

Comment: This is perfect, I basically need to clear every text box on the form, so this looks like the best way for it. Many thanks. I will try it out and get back with results.

Comment: The code above doesn't seem to do anything, no errors shown though. My textboxes are within a groupbox, if that makes any difference?

Comment: Change `this` in the code sample above to the name of your `GroupBox` (or whatever control is the direct parent of the `TextBox` controls you want to clear).

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do it that way. But you can define an array or list where you put the controls and then clear them. For example:

```
List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>();
textboxes.Add(tbPart1);
textboxes.Add(tbPart2);
textboxes.Add(tbPart3);
...
```

Then when you want to clear them

```
foreach (var tb in textboxes)
    tb.Clear();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
TextBox[] boxes = new [] {
    tbPart1,
    tbPart2,
    tbPart3,
    tbPart4,
    tbPart5,
    tbPart6,
    tbPart7
};

for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Length; i++)
{
    boxes[i].Clear();
}
```

Comment: I am more looking for a way to clean up my code and remove all the textbox code and have just 1 or 2 lines, as I have about 20 other text boxes I need cleared, and it looks messy. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use an array of textbox then you can do a loop depends the count of numbers of textboxes.

Comment: Could you add some explanation? Or remove this question completely, since other answers demonstrate exactly what you're advising with a code examples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if(ctrl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        ctrl.Text = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Answer number one by using *Control name* inside panel1

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string currentCtrlName;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < panel1.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            currentCtrlName = "textBox" + (i+1).ToString();
            panel1.Controls[currentCtrlName].Text = "";
        }

    }
```

## ==================
Answer number one by using *Control index* as a child inside panel1

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        for (int i = 0; i < panel1.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            panel1.Controls[i].Text = "";
        }

    }
```

==================